# Create an irregular border

Tags: javascript, css, border

I am trying to create an irregular border around a div, the div will contain text. I am currently using two different images and making them background on the top and bottom of the div. This method works out pretty well but the problem is the div can grow, i.e. it can have variable width and height depending on its content. So, in this case using images as background to achieve this effect is no longer viable.

Is there any way to create an irregular border using CSS and javascript? Obviously, the border should accommodate variable width and height.

I am trying to achieve something like this, but on all sides.

[image: I am trying to create this effect but on all sides]

Comment: "Winter is coming" (That amorphous blob looks like a wall of snow!)

Answer (score 1):

Use a background image for the div itself and CSS border-image for the borders. Here's an example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image

You can also use 2-3 divs to achieve what you are trying to do. Create an image which has the top decoration you want and set that as the background image. Then get another image with your side design, which is repeatable, but not so small that the pattern becomes apparent, and use that as the image with repeat-y enabled. Something like this

```
.image-top {
  background: img(url) no-repeat;
  min-height: 25px;
}
.image-middle {
  background: img(url2) repeat-y;
}

<div class="image-top">
</div>
<div class="image-middle">
  content goes here
</div>
```

or

```
.image-top {
  background: img(url) no-repeat;
  min-height: 25px;
}
.image-middle {
  background: img(url2) repeat-y;
}
.image-bottom {
  background: img(url3) no-repeat;
  min-height: 25px;
}

<div class="image-top">
</div>
<div class="image-middle">
  content goes here
</div>
<div class="image-bottom">
</div>
```

Comment: With a good image this could do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try `background-size:contain` using that image and then add some `padding` too keep the text away.  It'll scale but it might look pixelated if the box gets too large.  Otherwise, you'd need to make the edges repeatable which is probably near impossible given the image you've supplied.

PS. Reminds me of the days we all wanted rounded corners and now we flat design barely uses the border-radius property.

Comment: It is not necessary to use the exact same image. The border could change, it doesn't matter. But the border has to be irregular, not perfect lines.